# python - inner join 3 classes

Tags: python, django, django-models, inner-join

I have a problem, I don't know how to do an inner join (without raw sql) in python/django...

This is my classes:

```
class A(models.Model):
    parameter1 = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    parameter1 = models.CharField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(a)

class C(models.Model):
    parameter1 = models.CharField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(b)
```

How can i have have the same result using only django, as this request :

```
query = A.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id=B.a_id INNER JOIN C ON B.id=b_id')
```

Thanks

Comment: did you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ ?

Comment: Do you ask the same as here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610891

Comment: I read your posts, but it's not the same problem as mine.

Comment: how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178215

Comment: No i'm sorry, it doesn't help me. May be it's me, I should read again the django's doc. Tks.

Comment: It's okay, i found how to do this.

i create a function "detail" :
def detail(request, id):

    a = A.objects.select_related('b').get(pk=id)
    b = B.objects.select_related('a').filter(a_id=id)
    c = C.objects.select_related('b').filter(b__a_id=id)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `isnull` or any other field lookups to constrain data from A:

```
q = A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False, b__c__parameter1__isnull=False)
```

result query will be similar to this:

```
SELECT "appname_A"."id", "appname_A"."parameter1" FROM "appname_A"
INNER JOIN "appname_B" ON ("appname_A"."id" = "appname_B"."a_id")
INNER JOIN "appname_C" ON ("appname_B"."id" = "appname_C"."b_id")
WHERE ("appname_C"."parameter1" IS NOT NULL AND "appname_B"."id" IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY "appname_A"."id" ASC
```

and you should use `select_related` from `C` (**backwards**) if you want to select all data in one query from joined tables:

```
q = C.objects.filter(b__a__parameter1=SOMETHING).select_related()
```

result query will start from:

```
SELECT "appname_C"."id", "appname_C"."parameter1", "appname_C"."b_id",
       "appname_B"."id", "appname_B"."parameter1", "appname_B"."a_id",
       "appname_A"."id", "appname_A"."parameter1"
INNER JOIN ...
```